# Change soap address in web service made in Netbeans, made from java class

Tags: java, web-services, soap, netbeans, wsdl

I am new in creating webservice with Netbeans. I have successfully created a web service on localhost, and the wsdl soap address is: http://localhost:8084/DemoWeb/MyWebService

The class (MyWebService) is as follows:

```
    @WebService(serviceName = "MyWebService")
    public class MyWebService {   

       /** This is a sample web service operation */
       @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
       public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
           return "Hello " + txt + " !";
       } 
    }
```

However, on the live server (where this service will originally sit) has apache httpd set up, that does ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse to the tomcat, so a url like this: localhost:8084/DemoWeb/MyWebService  will be tranlsated like this: localhost/MyWebService

I would like to know how can i set up the soap address to point to this url. (the ProxyPass works for the webservice wsdl, so if you go to http://localhost/MyWebService?wsdl it will open the wsdl, but the wsdl then lists the wrong address.